# Is there a way to split data from a cell in a .xlsm to individual arrays in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have .xlsm files that contain 4 values that I want to be able to separate into columns of data. These values are all in a single cell in .xlsm files along with the column names.[image: A screenshot of how the values are structured is found here]

I tried reading in the file as

```
pd.read_excel("1.xlsm", delimiter = ",")
```

, but am not able to separate each value into a new column. I want to be able to call each column using pandas so I can access each column individually.

Answer (score 0):

That's not working because cell A3 for example contains that entire string. What you can do is split the string at the , which will return a list of Time(s), A, B, C, D.

```
df['A'].str.split(",", n=-1, expand=True)
```

The n=-1 means to do it for every comma it sees. And expand = True means it will create new columns for your information.

I can't test this with recreating your Excel file, so please let me know if it works or not. :)